# How to join multiple collections in MongoDB 3.4?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

please help me to join multiple collections in MongoDB 3.4

school_collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f9934b952255731e8dbfa17"),
    class:[]
}
```

class_collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f9a4398e146b6327457967b"),
    "school_id" : ObjectId("5f9934b952255731e8dbfa17"),
    "name" : "",
    "description" : ""
    students:[]
}
```

students_collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f9a4398e146b6327457967c"),
    "class_id" : ObjectId("5f9a4398e146b6327457967b"),
    "name" : "",
    "description" : ""
}
```

expected result:

```
{
    "_id" : "5f9934b952255731e8dbfa17",
        class: [
            {
                "_id": "5f9a4398e146b6327457967b",
                "name": "",
                "description": ""
         students: [
                    {
                      "_id" : "5f9a4398e146b6327457967c",
                      "name" : "",
                      "description" : ""
                    }
              ]
            }
        ]
}
```

I was able to get collection up to class by using `$lookup`, but how can I get students details array inside each class?

```
dbConnection.db().collection(db_collections.SCHOOL).aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: db_collections.CLASS,
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "class_id",
        as: "class"
    }
}])
```

Comment: Can you add the foreign field and local field in each of the collection?

Comment: updated the question, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MongoDB 3.4**

- `$lookup` join class collection
- `$lookup` join students collection
- `$addFields` to update class field, `$map` to iterate loop of class array and get students from students array, `$filter` to get matching students and return in students field

```
db.school.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "class",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "school_id",
      as: "class"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "students",
      localField: "class._id",
      foreignField: "class_id",
      as: "students"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      class: {
        $map: {
          input: "$class",
          as: "c",
          in: {
            _id: "$$c._id",
            school_id: "$$c.school_id",
            name: "$$c.name",
            description: "$$c.description",
            students: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$students",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$c._id", "$$this.class_id"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { students: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CYC-dFreCg7)